# mssql datatype change in PyQt5 to float and date change =PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(yyyy, mm, dd, 0, 0)

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]

Hi all, i have connected with mssql server and showing table data in to pyqt5 tablewidget.everything is working fine. but i can see the data type are change for some columns (which are mostly int type).
and date column also change as PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2016, 2, 4, 0, 0). from the table which are already float type i have no problems with that.
so , how to resolve this ? i mean i want to show datas in tableWidget same as Mssql data.

**Note1:** i used Convert(int,iinsightAccountID) in query_string , it worked. but i don't want to convert one by one column manually because i have too many columns.
**Note2:**:  i cannot changed dataType in mssql server, it always correct.

**mainWindow.py**

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QPushButton,QMenu
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from window import Ui_MainWindow
    from eventHandler import *
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.positionButton.clicked.connect(self.poscall)
        def poscall(self):
            input_value=self.lineEdit.text()
            type_value=str(self.comboBox.currentText()
            positionData=loadPosition(input_value,type_value)

            header_list = positionData[0]
            value_list =  positionData[1]
            no_rows = len(value_list)
            no_columns= len(header_list)

            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(no_rows)
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(no_columns)

            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tuple(header_list))
            self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
            self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

            for row in range(no_rows):
                for col in range(no_columns):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row,col,QTableWidgetItem(str(value_list[row][col])))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**eventHandler.py**

```
   from database import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def loadPosition(input_value,type_value):

    if type_value=="AccountID":
        query_string="SELECT iinsightaccountid,dtpositiondate,* from insightProcessing.dbo.insightPositions(nolock) where iinsightAccountID="+input_value

        mydata=loadData(query_string)
        header_list = mydata[0]
        value_list =  mydata[1]
        return (mydata)


    if type_value=="Account Number":
        query_string="SELECT  top 100 dtPositionDate,iinsightAccountID from insightProcessing.dbo.insightPositions(nolock) where vchCustodianAccountNumber="+input_value
        mydata=loadData(query_string)
        header_list = mydata[0]
        value_list =  mydata[1]
        return (mydata)
```

database.py

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc , what is wrong with my question?

Comment: With the information you provide me it is impossible to analyze your problem since the least I should do is reproduce your problem. Please read the link that I have provided you in addition to [ask] and pass the [tour] if you have not already done so.

Comment: @eyllanesc, when mssql server iinsightAccountiD column is "int type" , but  when i pull the datas in pyqt5 , insightAccountID column shows "float.type"

Comment: also dtpositionDate column showing date like : PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2016, 2, 4, 0, 0)

Comment: @eyllanesc, please edit my question if i posted unnecessary

Comment: On the contrary, your question has so little information that for this reason I ask you for the MRE.

Comment: @eyllanesc , i have edited my question , please resolve my issue